# Fixed sidebar with fixed footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make a sticky sidebar with a footer that doesn't move when the page is scrolled. I tried this css but its making the sidebar not appear at all.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

But the sidebar isn't showing up at all. I have a fiddle of a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15259/

Comment: You have it's width set to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this;

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: whatver;
    width:whateverpx;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

rename the nav as necessary for your page.